# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at (but file exists)

Tags: django, file, templates

I have an issue with template rendering.

Indeed django finds my templates files but each of them uses {% extends "base.html" %} and django does not find "base.html"

Django tried this path :

/home/gi-karna/hellodjango/tfjm2/inscription/templates/base.html (File does not exist)

and my template file is in :

/home/gi-karna/hellodjango/tfjm2/inscription/templates/inscription/home.html, error at line 2

It is real weird as the file "base.html" does exist at the first path. I don't know where the problem is.

I look forward to hearing from you soon

Comment: Posting your template settings will be helpful.

Comment: in your settings.py file, what are installed apps related to your application? Django will by default look for templates directory in each of the installed apps directory. This search is not recursive by default.

Comment: my app's name is "inscription" and it is in the installed apps liste in the settings